# Entity Framework Select where sum of column is greater than x

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a sql table with a number of cost entries for a unique Id.

here is a Simplified version of the table:

```
Table:
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public DateTime date {get;set;}
 public int Cost {get;set;}
}
```

I need to build an EF query to do the following:

```
select from the table where x.date.Date = DateTime.Now.date && SUM(x.cost) > 100.00)

and it should group by x.Id
```

Comment: How are you grouping the data? Or do you just mean "where Cost > 100"?

Comment: Very valid point, I totally forgot to add that to my question. I have added it now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a couple of things. For the data, it's simpler to get the start end end time and do a date range rather than trying to get only the date component. Secondly, just apply a second `Where` to filter out `SUM() > 100`:

```
var dateToCheck = DateTime.Now;
var start = dateToCheck.Date;
var end = dateToCheck.AddDays(1).Date;

var data = tables
    .Where(t => t.date >= start && t.date < end)
    .GroupBy(t => t.Id)
    .Where(g => g.Sum(t => t.Cost) > 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the date suggestion, As I am trying to only compare the month of the year. i don't care about day or seconds

Answer (score 2):

With you additional comment on the Post of DavidG

This is maybe what you are looking for

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var data = from entry in tables
           where entry.Date.Month == date.Month && entry.Date.Year == date.Year
           group entry.Cost by entry.Id into g
           where g.Sum() > 100
           select new { Id = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum() };
```